# Client side D3 line chart from node.js server data

Tags: node.js, d3.js, ejs

I'm trying to generate data on the server side (Node.JS) and then pass it via res.render to a view.ejs page for use in a simple D3 lineChart. I can hard code the data on the ejs page with a successful chart rendering.  But, when I try to pass the data object from Node via res.render, D3.data doesn't seem to recognize the data.

Here is the server side route:

```
router.get("/view", function(req,res){

let data = [
    {evalDate: 1598038171322, evalHypValue: 18},
    {evalDate: 1608038171322, evalHypValue: 27},
    {evalDate: 1618038171322, evalHypValue: 29},
    {evalDate: 1628038171322, evalHypValue: 30}, 
            ];

     res.render("view",
        {
          Data: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
});
```

And here is the view.ejs with the D3 code:

```
<div class="" id="hyp_chart"></div>

<script>
//NOTE: hard coded data works with the D3
//let data = [
//  {evalDate: 1598038171322, evalHypValue: 18},
//  {evalDate: 1608038171322, evalHypValue: 27},
//  {evalDate: 1618038171322, evalHypValue: 29},
//  {evalDate: 1628038171322, evalHypValue: 30}, 
//            ];

//But I can't get this next line to use my server side data as input to D3
let data = <%=JSON.parse(Data)%>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the evalDate / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Q");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.evalDate); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.evalHypValue); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#hyp_chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// gridlines in x axis function
function make_x_gridlines() {       
    return d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5)
}

// gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {       
    return d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(5)
}

// Get the data
// format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.evalDate = parseTime(d.evalDate);
      d.evalHypValue = Number(d.evalHypValue);
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.evalDate; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.evalHypValue; })]);

  // add the X gridlines
  svg.append("g")           
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(make_x_gridlines()
          .tickSize(-height)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

  // add the Y gridlines
  svg.append("g")           
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(make_y_gridlines()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

  // add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
    //   .datum(dataset)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

</script>
```

Thank you!!!